# Display number in rectangle

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, wxwidgets

Note that I am using Python3 and Phoenix.

I would like to display a number (double, but that does not matter now) formatted in some way (again, no matter what that way is) within a rectangle: almost a `wx.StaticText` but not editable by the user. This is to display some data coming from some hardware, such as a temperature.

Is there such a widget?

I tried with using the default `wx.StaticText` with a style but I must have done something wrong:

```
    hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

    title = wx.StaticText(parent, label=label)
    title.SetLabelMarkup("<b>{}</b>".format(label))
    hbox.Add(title, border=5)

    value = wx.StaticText(parent, label="3.141592", style=wx.BORDER_RAISED)
    value.SetWindowStyle(wx.BORDER_SIMPLE)
    hbox.Add(value, border=5)

    title = wx.StaticText(parent, label="\u2103")
    hbox.Add(title, border=5)
```

Shows this on Linux (Fedora 24, GTK):

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't using a `wx.TextCtrl` set to read only do the job?

```
Temp = wx.TextCtrl(panel1, value="3.141592", style=wx.TE_READONLY)
Temp.SetBackgroundColour('green')
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution indeed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to just use `wxStaticText` with a border style (e.g. `wxBORDER_SIMPLE`, ...). If you don't like the appearance this results in, it's pretty simple to make your own widget drawing whatever border you desire: just create a window, define its `wxEVT_PAINT` handler and draw the (presumably centered) text in it and a border outside of it.

Comment: Okay, that is simpler than I thought. However, I am still doing something wrong. Question updated with some code.

Comment: I'm not sure if border can be changed like this after creation under all platforms (which one do you use?). Try specifying the border style as ctor parameter to see if it helps.

Comment: Currently on Linux but the code should be portable to MS Windows 10 as well.

Comment: Sadly, no change. ☹

Comment: Maybe you use a GTK+ theme with invisible borders? This definitely does work for me under MSW (just checked on the "static" page of the standard wxWidgets "widgets" sample, which has menu items for changing borders).

Comment: That is possible…